# Bash (value too great for base)

Tags: linux, bash

I was modifying something that I found on the internet to customise my pi ssh login message and I ended up encountering errors.

Following is my code:

```
let upSeconds="$(/usr/bin/cut -d. -f1 /proc/uptime)"
let secs=$((${upSeconds}%60))
let mins=$((${upSeconds}/60%60))
let hours=$((${upSeconds}/3600%24))
let days=$((${upSeconds}/86400))
UPTIME=`printf "%d days, %02dh%02dm%02ds" "$days" "$hours" "$mins" "$secs"`

let totalSpace="$(df -Bm | grep /dev/root | awk {'print $4'})"
let freeSpace="$(df -Bm | grep /dev/root | awk {'print $3'})"
TOTAL=`echo "$freeSpace Mb (Free) / $totalSpace (Total)"`

# get the load averages
read one five fifteen rest < /proc/loadavg

echo "$(tput setaf 2)
   .~~.   .~~.    `date +"%A, %e %B %Y, %r"`
  '. \ ' ' / .'   `uname -srmo`$(tput setaf 1)
   .~ .~~~..~.
  : .~.'~'.~. :   Uptime.............: ${UPTIME}
 ~ (   ) (   ) ~  Memory.............: ${TOTAL}
( : '~'.~.'~' : )
 ~ .~ (   ) ~. ~
  (  : '~' :  )
   '~ .~~~. ~'
       '~'
$(tput sgr0)"
```

It return these errors and I don't know how to solve them:

```
/home/pi/.bash_profile: line 8: let: totalSpace=12688M: value too great for base (error token is "12688M")
/home/pi/.bash_profile: line 9: let: freeSpace=1562M: value too great for base (error token is "1562M")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you see in the error message, you get the unit (`M`) in the value of `totalSpace` and `freeSpace` when you just pull out the columns out of `df`.

Change those lines to

```
totalSpace="$(df -Bm | tr -d 'M' | grep /dev/root | awk {'print $4'})"
freeSpace="$(df -Bm | tr -d 'M' | grep /dev/root | awk {'print $3'})"
```

That will get rid of all Ms in the output of `df`.

Drop all `let`s too. They are ancient and not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: and eliminate an extra process by having `awk` match for `/dev/root`, i.e. `...tr -d 'M' | awk '/\/dev\/root/{print $4}'` .... Good luck.

Comment: @PaulSerander Actually, `df` can take a directory name and give you the info for its partition only... as in `df -Bm /`.

Comment: @Kusalananda : yes `df` can take an argument, but it still produces a header. Using the `awk /\/dev\/root/{print $4}'` solution automatically ignores the header. Good luck to all!